# vim x/y scrollbar hiding my commands and being really anoying

Tags: vim, cmd, scrollbar

i'm a new vim user since 2 weeks and i've currently have my biggest trouble for the moment on vim.
i always have a x and y scrollbar on my vim and the x one is very anoying because it cover my commands.
here is a screenshot of the scrollbars that appears when i use terminal inside of vim using `:term` / `:!dir`  or even when i save my vimrc or source it (`:so ~/.vimrc`)
if there is any solutions to it i will be really grateful, thanks for reading

[image]

Comment: What program are you using to run Vim? Native terminal vim wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: @wxz i run Vim from the the native terminal

Comment: What OS/terminal? This may be resolved with your terminal settings (maybe turning off horizontal scrollbar if possible). Another possibility is resizing your vim using `set lines` to be one line shorter in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @wxyz i use Windows 10 but there are no settings to disable scrollbar, i tried `set lines` but it didn't change anything. thanks

Comment: Wait, so is this powershell? Unless I'm mistaken, vim isn't natively on Windows. You have to install `gvim` or something. How did you install it?

Comment: Those scrollbars are not Vim's, they are you terminal emulator's. In Vim, what is the output of `:set lines columns`? In your terminal emulator, what shell are you using?

Comment: @romainl lines=63 I use my cmd to run Vim

Comment: @wxz yes it's not natively on Windows. I download it from [Vim website](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) and add it to my environnement variables ton run vim commands in cmd/powershell (I have the same issues on both on them)

Comment: @Cyprien, I asked for the output of `:set lines columns`. Also, what happens when you scroll? Are you still in Vim?

Comment: @romainl my bad lines=63 columns=240 and when i scroll it don't do anythings, the screen dont move

Comment: An easy solution if you don't have to use `powershell` is to just switch to `WSL` so you can use Vim "natively" in a Linux terminal.

Comment: @wxz so i download Ubuntu terminal and it's still showing scrollbars when i start vim in it

Comment: That's hard to believe. Are you opening `ubuntu` from powershell? If so, don't. Try opening `ubuntu` as its own app.

Comment: @wxz this is what i'm doing but in ubuntu when i scroll this actually moving elements https://zupimages.net/up/21/17/pg2k.png
https://zupimages.net/up/21/17/0dep.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with your layout settings in `Powershell` and `Ubuntu`. Right click on the top bar of either program, go to `Properties` and then go to the `Layout` tab. You can check the `Wrap text output on resize` box and that should get rid of your horizontal scrollbar, thereby allowing you to use Vim as normal. Alternatively, in the same menu, you can decrease the width of the screen buffer size so that it is smaller than the width of the window size.

[image: Powershell Properties Menu]

Comment: thanks for you answer, i tried and it don't work ...

Comment: What are your layout settings?

Comment: okay so putting width and height in both screen buffer size and window size the same seem to remove scrollbar thanks very much @wxy (put height of screen buffer size to 3000 make placement really weird for me)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.